# Jquery/ Javascript getting information from PHP scope issue?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get some information from our database and then use it in javascript/JQuery and I think I might be doing something wrong with the scope of the coding.

Here is the current segment of code on my phtml page (magento)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
echo 'var $image-paths = new Array();';
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($_child_products); $i++)
{
    echo '$image-paths[';
    echo $i;
    echo '] = ';
    echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_child_products[$i], 'image');
    echo ';';
}
?>
document.getElementById('main-image').href = $image-paths[1];
</script>
```

The bottom getElementById is just for testing to see if it really grabbed that image path.  So far the php stuff is working and echo'ing the correct links.  However, is simply echo'ing them not enough; does it actually register it into the javascript code?

Here is what my source code looks like on my server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $image-paths = new Array();
$image-paths[0] = http://staging.greencupboards.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5f  b8d27136e95/feeds/MrsMeyers/MRM-64565-a.jpg;
$image-paths[1] = http://staging.greencupboards.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/feeds/MrsMeyers/MRM-64566-a.jpg;
$image-paths[2] = http://staging.greencupboards.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/feeds/MrsMeyers/MRM-64568-a.jpg;
$image-paths[3] = http://staging.greencupboards.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/feeds/MrsMeyers/MRM-D43114-a.jpg;
document.getElementById('main-image').href = $image-paths[1];
</script>
```

But the image link does not change to image-path[1].  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$image-paths[0] = http://staging.greencupboards.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5f  b8d27136e95/feeds/MrsMeyers/MRM-64565-a.jpg;
                  ^-- no quote here, or at the end of the string
```

You're producing invalid javascript. Pop up your javascript console (shift-ctrl-J in chrome/firefox) and you'll see the error.

Producing javascript dynamically is problematic. Anytime you insert something from a PHP variable/function, you should run that through json_encode(), which guarantees you get valid javascript:

```
echo json_encode($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_child_products[$i], 'image'));
```

Or better yet, change the code to:

```
$links = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($_child_products); $i++)
    $links[] = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_child_products[$i], 'image');
}

echo '$image-paths = ', json_encode($links);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  However, I tried both methods for json_encode and utilized quotes, but the json_encode method is giving me blank URL's, it isn't actually grabbing anything through the PHP.  Ideas?

Comment: Does that helper function return its value, or directly output it? If it's direct output, then none of this'll work as it bypasses the json_encode/array building completely.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your asking, I get something like this...$image-paths[0] = "{}";$image-paths[1] = "{}";$image-paths[2] = "{}";  Maybe I am going about this problem incorrectly.

Comment: if that init() function does its own `echo $linktext` instead of `return $linktext`, then it's doing direct output, and the json-encode function never sees the link text. You'd need to mod the function to return, or use output buffering (ob_start() and company) to capture the output.

Comment: ohh I see what you mean.  Yes, the helper echo's the output, so it looks like this is way beyond the scope of what i'm able to do.  But I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can do something like `ob_start(); ...->init(..>); $link = ob_get_clean();` instead. That'll capture the output into `$link` instead of outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
echo 'var $image_paths = new Array();';
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($_child_products); $i++)
{
    echo '$image_paths[';
    echo $i;
    echo '] = "'; // Here the starting of quotes.
    echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_child_products[$i], 'image');
    echo '";'; // Here the ending of quotes.
}
?>
document.getElementById('main-image').href = $image_paths[1];
</script>
```

This should work now. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what you changed?

Comment: Javascript has no problem with variables having a `$` in the name... if it did, there'd be a LOT of jquery code that would never have worked in the first place.

Comment: @Marc - Many thanks for letting me know, I'm changing the answer also.